# Power BI Embedded Report Picker

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have an embedded site for my users to view a report.  I have one master login for Power BI that all customers are routed through.

Authentication and the request are done through a .NET backend using PowerBI.Api.V2.  Everything works well when I hardcode a single reportId and embed the fullscreen iframe.

My question is for customers that have multiple reports; Is there a built in report-picker-report that I can embed where the report selection is already handled for me?  Or should I work on building an interface after retrieving the list of reports my users can pick from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no built-in pickers. Power BI provides an API interface and you must implement these for yourself. Of course, you can build these pickers and make them available for us :)

To get list of workspaces you need to call [Get Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/groups/getgroups). This will give you a list of user's workspaces. You can show their `name` property values to the user, but you will need their `id` (the guid). When you know the id of a workspace, you can list the reports in it by calling [Get Reports In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreportsingroup). The same way you can call [Get Dashboards In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/dashboards/getdashboardsingroup) and [Get Tiles In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/dashboards/gettilesingroup).